# Including a bat file in a bat file

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

I have many bat files that share a common setup of variables. Instead of defining the same variables over and over again (and making errors in the process) I would like to include one bat file in all the others.

How do I do this? Excuse my newbie question but the last time I touched bat, it was a file called autoexec.bat, long ago...

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call another bat file with "call FILENAME".
Don't really know if that is sufficient for you.

Comment: sometimes it is just that :)

Comment: Do variables exist to the new batch file?  I think you'll need to pass them to the environment with the SET Command.